# Set environment variable for build in hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson, environment-variables

I am trying to put a maven2 project under continuous integration in hudson.
The project uses selenium for some integration testing.
Hudson is running on a headless linux.
I am using xvfb to start a x server session for selenium.

In order to run the tests, I need to export an environment variable named DISPLAY.
e.g.

```
export DISPLAY=:99
```

However, I don't want to set the variable on the box since it would affect all builds.
I have tried to do a shell execute using the m2 extra steps plugin but it doesnt work since it is executed in a separate bash file, meaning that environment variables are not persisted.

Is there a way to register the environment variable from hudson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a new feature in Hudson that allows you to specify [parameters for builds](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build). This looks like it does what you want.

Though note that:

> [image: warning]
>    This is still a very young feature, so feedback appreciated
>
> ...
>
> The parameter[s] are available as environment parameters. So e.g. a shell ($FOO, %FOO%) or Ant ( ${env.FOO} ) can access these values.

Comment: I'm not convinced this actually answers the question that was asked - how do I set environment variables in the same shell as Maven is invoked?

These parameters are quite useful, but it's not quite what the user was asking for - and it also doesn't allow you to edit environmental variables that are currently there i.e. you can't get it to call itself.

For example, export PATH=/usr/bin/foo:$PATH won't work, as it does not recognise $PATH

Comment: @Spedge you are conflating reading and setting of environment variables. The question asked how to set a variable and the mechanism described does exactly that. In your example you are doing both a set and a read, which was not asked for.

Comment: @Rich Seller - Apologies sir. I have done some work on this now, and will elaborate in an answer beneath (as there's not enough room in a comment).

Answer (score 10):

fyi, I'm releasing [the setenv plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Setenv+Plugin) for Hudson today (assuming java.net recovers enough for me to do so!) - it behaves similarly to the parameterized build functionality, but with a simpler UI (just a textarea for input - key/value pairs are separated by newlines) and without the need to provide values for the parameters at build-time.

Answer (score 3):

Hudson's Node Properties would do a good job here.  But if you're looking for a more automated way of assigning the screen number, you'll need to do a little more work, perhaps tying into the [port-allocator plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Port+Allocator+Plugin), or writing a new BuildWrapper plugin which starts up xvfb automatically, and sets the SCREEN environment variable on behalf of the build.

If you're willing to switch to a different X server for testing, you can try the [Xvnc plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Xvnc+Plugin) for Hudson.  It will start the vncserver automatically, and set the SCREEN environment variable as well.   It also has the ability to take a screenshot when tests are finished, and show that in the job's Hudson page.

Comment: How do you *add* (not set) to an environment variable such as `PATH`?

Comment: @Sridhar I'd suggest starting an entirely new question for that.

Comment: @Sridhar: There is no way to do it if the new variable value should survive the current build step.

Answer (score 1):

I've found running selenium using `xvfb-run` to be more reliable than setting DISPLAY, so this might work for you. So:

```
xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the selenium maven plugin?

The plugin could be configured to start Xvfb, run the tests and then stop it.

using this pom.xml configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>xvfb</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xvfb</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>selenium</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start-server</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <background>true</background>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

the details are here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/examples/headless-with-xvfb.html

Answer (score 0):

As per my response to the accepted answer, here are my findings.

**Beware Un-initialised Variables**

When using the Parametrization feature in Hudson, you can append environmental variables to the end of a string - provided that they contain something in the first place.

For example, if the environment variable $FOO is blank, and you were to use the following line in a String Parameter...

```
/usr/bin/ladeda/:$F00
```

then the environment variable will read /usr/bin/ladeda/:$F00.

However, if I did

```
export F00=/usr/bin/fiddledede
```

then the exported variable would be....

```
/usr/bin/ladeda/:/usr/bin/fiddledede
```

When I initially ran this as a test, I had not worked this out - and thus thought the parameter feature was not accepting external environment variables, when it actually was (they just had to contain something).